# ¿Hay sitios de Robótica, Electrónica, Hosting web, Lenguas extranjeras, Medicina, Historia, Ciencias de Computación y Psicología en Stack Exchange?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

Mientras buscaba en Stack Overflow, estuve viendo si existian estas temáticas aquí pero la verdad no veo si estén. Si existen, ¿me podríais pasar el link o el nombre?

Temáticas que buscaba (no importa si están en inglés):

- Robótica e Electrónica.
- Hosting Web.
- Lenguas extranjeras (inglés, francés, etc.).
- Medicina.
- Historia Mundial o algo parecido de Estados Unidos.
- Ciencias de la computación.
- Psicología.

Gracias por su atención espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Puedes buscar en la lista de todos los sitios de Stack Exchange en [este link](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sitios:

- Robótica e Electrónica: https://robotics.stackexchange.com.
- Hosting Web: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/, no en su totalidad.
- Medicina: https://health.stackexchange.com.
- Historia Mundial o algo parecido de Estados Unidos: https://history.stackexchange.com.
- Ciencias de la computación: https://cs.stackexchange.com.
- Psicología: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com.
- Lenguas extranjeras (inglés, francés, etc.)

  - https://chinese.stackexchange.com/
  - https://english.stackexchange.com
  - https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/
  - https://french.stackexchange.com
  - https://german.stackexchange.com/
  - https://italian.stackexchange.com/
  - https://japanese.stackexchange.com/
  - https://korean.stackexchange.com/
  - https://latin.stackexchange.com/
  - https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/
  - https://russian.stackexchange.com/
  - https://spanish.stackexchange.com/ (no sería extranjera :)
  - https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Gracias amigo por ayudarme.

Comment: Para Hosting web puede que [webmasters.se] tenga algo.

Comment: Sí, confirmado. Tienen etiquetas como [looking-for-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-hosting) y [web-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting).

Answer (score 0):

> Lo ideal es que las preguntas sean específicas, que en este caso sería preguntar por un sitio en particular, pero aquí en Meta somos más laxos.

La red de sitios sobre preguntas y respuestas se llama **Stack Exchange**. Esta tiene como sitio http://stackexchange.com. Dicho sitio tiene la página [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) en la cual se listan todo los sitios que forma parte de la red. En [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) puedes revisar las propuestas de nuevos sitios.

Para los que saben inglés, las preguntas generales sobre la red deberían realizarlas en [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com),quienes hablan español y no saben o tienen una pregunta que no están del todo ciertos o cómodos en realizarla en inglés, lo pueden hacer aquí, el cual es el primer sitio graduado en el que el idioma oficial es el español.

Comment: oh lo siento y gracias

Comment: @gilbertoquintero No tienes que pedir disculpas, al contrario, perdona el que no haya puesto atención al tono de mi respuesta. En ocasiones, como en este caso, me limito a dar los datos.

Answer (score 0):

aunque esta pregunta ya se resolvio en si buscando bien encontre esta web : 
https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/
Es para estudiantes que quieran aprender un segundo idioma algo asi leei en su descripcion.