# ¿Stack Exchange Inc no ha pensado en crear estos siguientes sitios?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

Estuve viendo el catálogo de la red de *Stack Exchange Inc* y estuve viendo que algunas de los siguientes temáticas no existen en *Stack Exchange* y me preguntaba si no se lo han planteado.

Miré en el sitio *[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)* y no vi nada parecido.

¿Puede algún moderador contestar si están pensando en eso? y si es no, ¿Por qué?

Los siguientes sitios estuve pensando y viendo que no existen:

- Expertos de resultados en buscadores y mercadotecnia web.
- Expertos de hospedaje y administración de instalaciones de red o algo parecido.
- Usuarios de *iPhone* (solo vi una pero era para *Android*).
- Programación de drones (lo más parecido que yo he visto es el sitio de robótica).

Comment: En cuanto a hosting y SEO, se te respondo en tu pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2054/127. Sobre iPhone en [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cualquier usuario de nuestra red tiene la habilidad de sugerir nuevos sitios para Stack Exchange.  Vi que tienes temas interesantes y pienso que hay otros que también les interese lo mismo.  ¿Por qué no vas y haces una sugerencia en el Area51?

Las razones por las no existen esos temas es que no las han propuesto. Si te motiva el tener esos temas, te sugiero que empiezes por ahí. Ten en mente que el proceso tarda tiempo y que hay de definir el sitio antes de que se acepte y se lanze.

---

**Actualización**

Al leer la pregunta, me supongo que el sitio sugerido va a ser en inglés.  Si ese no es el caso, no se va a poder lanzar un sitio en español aparte de este por ahora. La propuesta se cerraría y se recibiría la siguiente notificación:

> **Non-English sites**
>
> Unfortunately, we are not currently accepting
> proposals for non-English sites — See the [Internationalization 'State
> of the Stack'](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack) notice for details.

En otras palabras, si el sitio que se a sugerir va a ser en inglés, adelante.  Si va a ser en otro idioma, mejor que no se proponga.  Si en un futuro esto cambia, les aviso de inmediato.

Comment: Hace tiempo se publicó que no iba a haber nuevos sitios internacionales por un tiempo. Procedo a actualizarme en la materia :)

Comment: Anotaciones sobre lo que voy encontrando. En [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/133145) Tim Post dice "After Spanish, it's going to be a bit of time before we're ready to take on another language." Sugiero ver el historial de la pregunta :)

Comment: En [Internationalization 'State of the Stack'](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/133145), de nuevo, Tim Post dice "We wish we could support additional sites in the languages we've currently finished translating, because the enthusiasm we've seen for them is amazing. We're going to keep working on it, and when we're ready, we promise to let you know."

Comment: Sería bueno tener sub-sitios en español, como dijeron alguna vez.